# how to add debug flags on compilation script execution:

Tags: build, build-process, build-script

I have a simple ./compile.make script that produces a bunch of object .o files. The contents are like this (first 5 lines printed):

compile.make:

```
gfortran -c -O3 active.f
gfortran -c -O3 alchemy.f
gfortran -c -O3 analysis.f
```

I run the script by doing ./compile.make. I'd like to compile everything with the -g flag so I can debug using (gdb) but I was wondering if there is a better way to add the "-g" flag without having to manually edit every line of my compile.make file.

*EDIT: I know that find/replace option is available and not much of a hassle at all. I was just curious as to whether the flags can be added upon execution of the script.

Comment: Have you considered moving over to a tool like `make`? I think it would save you many headaches, long-term.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/Find_and%20Replace_with_Sed.html